# How to make several custom looks of jScrollbar in Synth LaF?

Tags: java, css, swing, synth

In our application we have to use css to customize the look of Swing components. Right now we have some manually written css engine, but it is slow and requires a lot of additional code to apply one more css file. So now we try to use Synth look and feel to make ui changes more *native*.

For the most of components we set names and use them for binding to styles. But also there are several scrollbars, which have different css and though different look. The only way to affect scrollbars' thumb is to user region ScrollBarThumb, we can't set a name to it as it is not a JComponent. Due to using region instead of name it's not possible to have different looking thumbs. Is there any workaround?

Comment: The name of components use hierarchy like "chat.tabbedpane.panel.label", so it is possible to make something like this: if name contains "chat" draw scrollbar1. I hope there is some better way to do this.

Comment: in the case that you use [Classic Synth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) edit your question with xml file and [SSCCE](http://sscce/)

Answer (score 3):

- from instances of Synt L&F I'd be use only `Nimbus`, crazy example about [Nimbus L&F](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html), rest on methods is in [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary)

[image] [image]

from code (Java6)

```
import com.sun.java.swing.Painter;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class ScrollDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ScrollDemo() {
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        String[] columnNames = {"Column"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}, {"E"}, {"F"},
            {"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}, {"E"}, {"F"},
            {"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}, {"E"}, {"F"},
            {"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}, {"E"}, {"F"},
            {"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}, {"E"}, {"F"},};

        add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(data, columnNames)));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception fail) {
        }
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ScrollBar:ScrollBarThumb[Enabled].backgroundPainter",
                new FillPainter(new Color(255, 169, 191)));
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ScrollBar:ScrollBarThumb[MouseOver].backgroundPainter",
                new FillPainter(new Color(127, 255, 191)));
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ScrollBar:ScrollBarTrack[Enabled].backgroundPainter",
                new FillPainter(new Color(0, 212, 255)));
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ScrollBar:\"ScrollBar.button\".size", 20);
        //UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ScrollBar.decrementButtonGap", 10);
        //UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ScrollBar.incrementButtonGap", 10);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScrollDemo scrollDemo = new ScrollDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}

class FillPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {

    private final Color color;

    public FillPainter(Color c) {
        color = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
    }
}
```